# How can I set wp_dropdown_users so that it shows only authors?

Tags: users, author

I want to list in a drop-down box all users who have role "author"

How can i do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a  function which gives you all users which have role author in a drop down list.

**Note**: It is a dummy example modify it as you want( put this function in `functions.php` or custom `plugin` ).

**Use**: Call this function any where in theme like `<?php ravs_author_dropdown_list(); ?>`

```
function ravs_author_dropdown_list() {
    // query array
    $args = array(
        'role' => 'author'
    );
    $users = get_users($args);
    if( empty($users) )
      return;
    echo'<select>';
    foreach( $users as $user ){
        echo '<option value="'.$user->data->user_login.'">'.$user->data->display_name.'</option>';
    }
    echo'</select>';
}
```

Comment: I am noticing in the admin area when adding such dropdowns to filter users in media, posts or any CPT... WP_User_Query fails once you do a search and the dropdown does not re-appear. I have tried, a similar method above. 'wp_dropdown_users' and directly calling "$user_search = new WP_User_Query('role=subscriber');". I get no results at all once it lands on the search results page.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, adding a response since as the accepted answer uses a custom method yet WordPress supports this in the `wp_dropdown_users` method:

Use:

```
 wp_dropdown_users(['who' => 'authors']);
```

To query other roles [though not asked for in this question], you can use the `role` parameter, introduced in WordPress 4.7.0:

```
 wp_dropdown_users(['role' => 'authors']);
```

More here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_users/

Answer (score -1):

Use WordPress' built-in `wp_dropdown_users` with an advanced query as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142789/change-wp-dropdown-users-filter-by-user-role